# SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=xxxxxx' does not provide an export named 'AxiosError'

Tags: typescript, axios, vuejs3

I'm going to import `AxiosError` into my Vue project. `AxiosError` is a class, not a type definition. When I run the project, I get an error `SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=xxxxxx' does not provide an export named 'AxiosError'`, How can I import `AxiosError` and run the project properly?

Here is part of my code:

```
import axios, { AxiosError, type AxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";

export interface BaseRes {
  result?: string;
  data?: any;
  msg?: string;
}

const instance = axios.create({
  timeout: 3000,
});

const get = async <T extends BaseRes>(
  url: string,
  params?: any,
  config?: AxiosRequestConfig
) => {
  try {
    const res = await instance.get<T>(url, { ...config, params });
    return res.data;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
      return error.response?.data as T;
    }
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Comment: Axios version ?

Comment: And add your TS config